# controlling a YCC365 Plus IP camera using Python?

Tags: python, linux, opencv

I've successfully set up image reception, but when it comes to camera rotation control, it's a whole different challenge because this type of camera doesn't work with the ONVIF library.

I have already tried OpenCV for image reception using the camera's IP address.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the python requests libary to controll it.
Basicly you can send the request to the server like pressing the ptz buttons.

First open the dev options (chrome f12) and start recording.
Press one ptz button.
copy the request as nodejs fetch.
conver it to work in python (the headers variable is the same, body is the data just make it to a dict like the headers)
fetch("the url is here")

after that you can make the request with that:
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=headers)

the headers is always the same, you just need the data in every reqests